# How to choose learning models for different levels of a Stacking Ensemble?

Tags: ensemble-learning

I was wondering if there is any specific rule for designing the architecture of a Stacking Ensemble (e.g. number of levels, models in each level, and models in general). Also, can there be an overlap between the models of different levels? Thanks!